# How can I do a dictionary format with f-string in Python 3 .6?

Tags: python, dictionary, format, f-string

How can I do this format with a Python 3.6 F-String?

```
person = {'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23}

print('My name {0[name]} and my age {1[age]}'.format(person, person))
print('My name {0} and my age {1}'.format(person['name'], person['age']))
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Well, a quote for the dictionary key is needed.

`f'My name {person["name"]} and my age {person["age"]}'`

Comment: Just use the different quotes between a whole string and items. If you quote the string in double quotes, use single quotes for the keys. Both single quotes and double quotes act the same function in python.

Comment: Thanks 
what about that?
print('My name is {name} and my age is {age} and my salary is {salary}.'.format(**person))

Comment: That is the `str.format()` method , the different between f-string and str.format is in how index lookups are performed, as you have to quote the key from dictionary in `f-string`, but auto converted from index value to the string in `str.format()`

Comment: In Python 3.12+, you may use the same quotation marks, e.g., `f'My name {person['name']} and my age {person['age']}'`

Answer (score 53):

Depending on the number of contributions your dictionary makes to a given string, you might consider using `.format(**dict)` instead to make it more readable, even though it doesn't have the terse elegance of an f-string.

```
>>> person = {'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23}
>>> print('My name is {name} and my age is {age}.'.format(**person))
```

Output:

> My name is Jenne and my age is 23.

While this option is situational, you might like avoiding a snarl up of quotes and double quotes.

Comment: The question is about Python 3.6 f-strings explicitly, while you explain your answer clearly, this is not about what is being asked.

Comment: true enough, I wrote this comment having recently put an f string in some of my own work like this: `f'some text {mydict['mydumbmistake']} more text'` vs `f'some text {mydict["thisworks"]} more text'` and visually the error was hard for me to spot (maybe I'm just rubbish), so love f strings as I do, its one place where the old style feels ligher on its feet and less chance of a dumbo like myself making yet another error.

Comment: You could use the `format_map` function
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map
like this `print('My name is {name} and my age is {age}.'.format_map(person))`

Comment: @dbow is there any difference between `.format_map(dict)` and `.format(**dict)`?

Answer (score 28):

Both of the below statements will work on Python 3.6 onward:

1. `print(f'My name {person["name"]} and my age {person["age"]}')`
2. `print(f"My name {person['name']} and my age {person['age']}")`

Please mind the single `'` and double `"` quotes in the above statements, as placing them wrong will give a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

The string pkuphy posted is correct, and you have to use quotes to access the dictionary:

```
f'My name {person["name"]} and my age {person["age"]}'
```

Your original string works for the `str.format()`-function:

```
>>> person = {'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23}
>>> print('My name is {person[name]} and my age is {person[age]}.'.format(person=person))
```

Output:

> My name is Jenne and my age is 23.

The first `person` references all occurrences in the format-string, the second gives the variable to fill in.

Answer (score 4):

This will work.

```
f'My name {person["name"]} and my age {person["age"]}'
```

if `name` is a property of `obj`, `f'name is {obj[name]}'`, but for a dict as in this question, you can direct access the key `f'name is {person["name"]}'`.

Comment: error so that is why i am asking:    f'My name {person[name]} and my age {person[age]}'
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: Did you enclose name and age in parentheses as proposed?

Comment: Also note that this will not work in Python 3.5 or lower. F-strings were introduced in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

You have one object alone, which does not help understanding how things work. Let's build a more complete example.

```py
person0 = {'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23}
person1 = {'name': 'Jake', 'age': 29}
person2 = {'name': 'John', 'age': 31}
places = ['Naples', 'Marrakech', 'Cape Town']

print('''My name {0[name]} and my age {0[age]},
your name {1[name]} and your age {1[age]},
my favourite place {3[0]}'''.format(person0, person1, person2, places))
```

You can also access complete objects from the arguments list, like in:

```py
print('{2}'.format(person0, person1, person2, places))
```

Or select attributes, even cascading:

```py
print('{3.__class__.__name__}'.format(person0, person1, person2, places))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick stringification of a dictionary using an f-string without typing key manually

I was looking for a simple solution, in order to make a dictionary key, value pair a simple pair without the need to dig to each key of the dictionary.

```py
person = {'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23}
stringified_dict = ' '.join([f'{k.capitalize()} {v}' for k,v in person.items()])
print(f'In a Variable -->   {stringified_dict}')

# function
def stringify_dict(dict_val:dict) -> str:
    return ' '.join([f'{k.capitalize()} {v}' for k,v in dict_val.items()])

stringified_dict = stringify_dict({'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23})
print(f'Using Function -->  {stringified_dict}')


# lambda
stringify_dict = lambda dict_val: ' '.join([f'{k.capitalize()} {v}' for k,v in dict_val.items()])
stringified_dict = stringify_dict({'name': 'Jenne', 'age': 23})
print(f'Using Lambda -->    {stringified_dict}')
```

#### Output

```
In a Variable -->   Name Jenne Age 23
Using Function -->  Name Jenne Age 23
Using Lambda -->    Name Jenne Age 23
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on python 3.9.7 and I cannot explain why:

```py
>>> d = {'a': 'A'}
>>> "d.a: {d[a]}".format(d=d)
'd.a: A'
```

For some reason, it seems quotes should be left out when accessing dictionary keys in a format string.