# How to reference a dictionary to fill variables in a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to work out how to complete a task that asks the following:

Create a string and use a method to generate a description of the new car as shown below. Print it – it should be formatted like the text below (including the line breaks).

```
Yesterday I bought a [Make] [Model].
  
It’s not “too” old. It was made in [year] …  

I like it, though. It’s [colour], and it has [doors] doors!
```

The variables (make, model, year, colour and doors) need to be populated from a dictionary.

I have programmed the dictionary to look like this:

```
Car = {
'Make': 'Mitsubishi',
'Model': 'Lancer',
'Year': '2002',
'Colour': 'Green',
'Doors': '4',
}
```

How can i fill the variables in that string of text by referencing the dictionary 'Car'?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488137/how-to-do-a-dictionary-format-with-f-string-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template string, and then burst the dictionary values to format it. Example.

```
fstr = "Yesterday I bought a {} {}.\n\nIt’s not “too” old. It was made in {} …\n\nI like it, though. It’s {}, and it has {} doors!"

Car = {
'Make': 'Mitsubishi',
'Model': 'Lancer',
'Year': '2002',
'Colour': 'Green',
'Doors': '4',
}
print(fstr.format(*Car.values()))
```

Gives an output like

```
Yesterday I bought a Mitsubishi Lancer.

It’s not “too” old. It was made in 2002 …

I like it, though. It’s Green, and it has 4 doors!
```

So, you can apply the format with any dictionary you want.
**Condition**: You have to make sure the key/values are in the same order of the fillers.

Comment: You can accept the answer and upvote it, if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

python uses f-strings for this. You can use f-strings to pass variables to your string, while still keep it readable.

```
output = f"Yesterday I bought a {Car['Make']} {Car['Model']}."
```

you use `\n` to represent a newline, and `\` to escape any "" in the string itself:

```
output = f"Yesterday I bought a {Car['Make']} {Car['Model']}.\nIt’s not \“too\” old. It was made in {Car['Year']}"
```

extra: Pythons PEP8 style guides mention that variable names (like your dictionary) should always start with a lowercase.

Edit: Thanks to Timus for pointing out a small error. added `''` around dict keys.

Comment: This needs the dictionary to exist when the string is created. Which affects its reusability. So, maybe [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?#str.format) or even better [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format_map#str.format_map) might be a better idea?

Comment: Thank you for your timely response. I attempted that however I end up with an error stating that "Make' is not defined. The entire code is below.

'''Car = {
  'Make': 'Mitsubishi',
  'Model': 'Lancer',
  'Year': '2002',
  'Colour': 'Green',
}
print(Car)

Car['Year'] = '2011'
Car['Colour'] = 'Blue'
print(Car)

NewCar = Car.copy()
NewCar['Doors'] = '4'
print (NewCar)
print (Car)

CarString = f"Yesterday I bought a {Car[Make]} {Car[Model]}.\nIt’s not \“too\” old. It was made in {Car[year]}"

print(CarString)'''

Comment: I am very new to this so apologies for the formatting of my reply and code.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I forgot to add `""` around the keys in the dictionary. so `{car[Make]}` is now `{car["Make"]}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Build a string with the dictionary keys as placeholders (included in curly braces), and then use [`.format_map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?#str.format_map) with the dictionary as argument on it:

```
string = '''Yesterday I bought a {Make} {Model}.
  
It’s not “too” old. It was made in {Year} …  

I like it, though. It’s {Colour}, and it has {Doors} doors!'''

Car = {
    'Make': 'Mitsubishi',
    'Model': 'Lancer',
    'Year': 2002,
    'Colour': 'Green',
    'Doors': 4,
}

print(string.format_map(Car))
```

(The ordering of the dictionary is irrelvant.)