# How would I convert a format string with quotes into an f-string with nested quotes?

Tags: python, f-string

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43488137/175051) but I think I have more nested quotes and it's doing my head in.

How would I convert the following line into an f-string?

```
file.write('python -c "{code}"'.format(code="open('test.txt', 'w');"))
```

Comment: `s = "open('test.txt', 'w');"; f'python -c "{s}"'` -> `'python -c "open(\'test.txt\', \'w\');"'`

Comment: `'python -c "{code}"'.format(code="open('test.txt', 'w');")` -> `'python -c "open(\'test.txt\', \'w\');"'`

Answer (score 1):

There's barely anything to do here:

```
code="open('test.txt', 'w');"
file.write(f'python -c "{code}"')
```

You can of course also put the value of the variable in the f-string, but that would be silly:

```
file.write(f'python -c "{"open(\'test.txt\', \'w\');"}"')
```

Because replacing a string with a string is just, you know, inserting a string, no string formatting needed

```
file.write('python -c "open(\'test.txt\', \'w\');"')
```

Comment: yeah, I guess I was going for option 2 but as you say, it's hardly doing anything useful.  Thought originally f-strings didn't allow escape chars, but tis Monday and all bets are off mentally ;)

Comment: `f'python -c "{"open(\'test.txt\', \'w\');"}"'` is not valid this would throw `SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`

Comment: @Ch3steR is right, can't have escapes within an f-string :/